# C++ set of HashMap functions not outputting properly. No errors given

Tags: c++, function, vector, hashmap

I am going to provide all of my code below because I cannot figure out where the error is.

I do not understand why it is printing the title twice for the final function

Any help is greatly appreciated. All notes I have and code I have looked at online seem to have the same code structure as me so I do not understand why it is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


int findDate (unordered_map <int, string> employeeInfo, string employeeName)
{
    int answer = -1;
        for(auto item:employeeInfo)
        {
            if(item.second==employeeName)
               answer=item.first;
        }
        return answer;
}

int totalSignedUp (unordered_map <int, string> employeeInfo)
{
    int count=0;
    for (auto item:employeeInfo)
        count=count+1;
    return count;
}

void printMonth (string title, unordered_map <int, string> employeeInfo)
{
    cout<<title<<"\n";
    printf("Date    Name of Employee\n");
    for(auto item: employeeInfo)
    {
        cout << item.first << "    " << item.second << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{    
        unordered_map <int, string> employeeInfo;
        employeeInfo[1]="Ben";
        employeeInfo[2]="Erica";
        cout<<findDate(employeeInfo, "Erica")<<"\n";
        cout<<totalSignedUp(employeeInfo)+"\n";
        printMonth("Volunteers", employeeInfo);
    
}
```

Sorry for posting my entire code but I cannot pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: `employeeInfo[date]=employeeName` The parameter is not a reference, so that change disappears when the function ends. "why the vector functions return so many warnings" - you should not ignore these warnings - they usually are telling you something useful.

Comment: it is returning hundreds of warnings so it is hard to consume them all

Comment: I see your point with the reference. The dictionary is not being changed outside of the function? How could i fix this?

Comment: Just add an `&` before `employeeInfo` in the parameter list.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have gotten everything to work properly except the 2 functions that return a vector

Comment: @SierraWalker FYI:  Please note that each of the functions you wrote can be done in one line of C++ code.  Also, your `findEmployee` uses a linear search -- this defeats the entire purpose of what an `unordered_map` brings you.  The purpose of a map is to do fast lookups of the key.  The `unordered_map` has a `find()` method that you should be using.

Comment: `int totalSignedUp (unordered_map <int, string> employeeInfo)` -- This should be just `return employeeInfo.size();` -- There is no need to write a `for` loop.  I think a lot of the issues you are having stem from writing *too much* code, instead of using the member functions available for `unordered_map`.  The more code you write, the more chance bugs can occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

1. You are passing `std::unordered_map` by value.  What this means is that the function is working on a temporary copy of the map.  The temporary copy is then destroyed at the end of the function, thus you will not see any changes when the function returns.
2. You are writing functions that you do not need to write.  The one glaring case is that you are using a loop to find a key value in `std::unordered_map`.  This defeats the entire purpose of `unordered_map`, as it is used for fast lookups.  You should be using the `unordered_map::find()` method to search for the key.
3. You have code that will compile, but is clearly wrong probably due to typos.

   Here is an example:

   `cout<<totalSignedUp(employeeInfo)+"\n";`

   Clearly the extraneous `+` isn't supposed to be there.

Here is a rewrite of your code, addressing the issues outlined:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using EmployeeInfo = std::unordered_map<int, std::string>;

bool addEmployee(EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo, std::string employeeName, int date)
{
    auto pr = employeeInfo.insert({date, employeeName});
    return pr.second;
}

std::string findEmployee (EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo, int date)
{
    auto iter = employeeInfo.find(date);
    if ( iter != employeeInfo.end())
        return iter->second;
    return {};        
}

int findDate (EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo, std::string employeeName)
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(employeeInfo.begin(), employeeInfo.end(),
                            [&](auto& pr) { return pr.second == employeeName;});
    if ( iter != employeeInfo.end())
        return iter->first;
    return -1;
}

int totalSignedUp (EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo)
{
    return employeeInfo.size();
}

std::vector<std::string> employeesByDate (EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo, 
                                          int startDate, int endDate)
{
    std::vector <std::string> names;
    for ( auto& item : employeeInfo)
    {
        if (item.first >=startDate && item.first <= endDate)
            names.push_back(item.second);
    }
    return names;                 
}

std::vector<std::string> employees (EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo)
{
    std::vector<std::string> employees;
    for(auto& item : employeeInfo)
        employees.push_back(item.second);
    return employees;
    
}
void printMonth (std::string title, EmployeeInfo& employeeInfo)
{
    std::cout<<title<<"\n";
    std::cout << "Date    Name of Employee\n";
    for(auto& item: employeeInfo)
    {
        std::cout << item.first << "    " << item.second << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{    
    EmployeeInfo employeeInfo;
    employeeInfo[1]="Ben";
    employeeInfo[2]="Erica";
    std::cout << "Adding employee\n";
    std::cout << (addEmployee(employeeInfo,"Sierra", 13)?"Added OK":"Not Added") << "\n";
    std::cout << "\nFinding employee\n";
    std::cout << findEmployee(employeeInfo, 13) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\nFinding date of Erica\n";
    std::cout<< findDate(employeeInfo, "Erica")<<"\n";
    std::cout << "\nNumber of employees\n";
    std::cout << totalSignedUp(employeeInfo) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\nPrinting employees:\n";
    printMonth("Volunteers", employeeInfo);
}
```

Output:

```
Adding employee
Added OK

Finding employee
Sierra

Finding date of Erica
2

Number of employees
3

Printing employees:
Volunteers
Date    Name of Employee
13    Sierra
2    Erica
1    Ben
```

Not the prettiest output, but it appears.

The changes made were basically what was outlined above as to the mistakes you were making.

1. Note the usage of `using` to give an alias to the `unordered_map`. This makes the coding simpler and less terse.
2. Note the usage of `unordered_map::find()` to search for the date.
3. In `addEmployee`, the `unordered_map::insert()` is used.  If the item already existed, the returned `std::pair` has a `second` that will be set to `false`.  This replaces your entire logic of setting a `bool` to `false`.
4. When searching for the name, since the name isn't a key value, this is where a linear search would have to be done.  Given that, the `std::find_if` is used to linearly search through the map.  The returned iterator will either point to the found entry, or `employeeInfo.end()` if not found.

The rest of the changes should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank You! I just wrote so much before I focused on the errors that it all got jumbled together, made it hard to find the problems. Really appreciate the full explanations!